# PHP Performance/bytecode caching

Tags: php

I'm currently studying to take the Zend exam and some things are not clear to me. Zend requires that we know the "**Performance / bytecode Cacing**." Reading the documentation on php.net I could not find anywhere.

http://www.zend.com/en/services/certification/php-5-certification/

Can anyone explain me what is the **Performance/bytecode caching** and where i can read more about that...

Also he want to know "Config"... I'm not sure what zend exactly is meant?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's about APC. You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Comment: No i think is not that. I dont see on that page bytecode caching. Omg i dont know for what is that important...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612945/what-is-a-bytecode-cache-and-how-can-i-use-one-in-php , http://devzone.zend.com/1812/using-apc-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

I think it's talking about OPcache and you can find it in the php official website documentation

[OPcache](https://www.php.net/opcache)