# Having a really long PHP file

Tags: php

I'm kinda new to PHP and I am writing a new script, so I have a general wondering.. Is it okay to have a large PHP file? Or I should just split it? By large I mean 3000 Lines <

Everything is working fine, I just want to know if this may affect the response time or something..

Comment: It all depends on what's in the file.

Comment: The file is used to handle site classes and forms submission.

Comment: I'd consider breaking it up into logically distinct sections, just to make it easier to edit the code. Certainly I'd break out the classes into their own files and use an autoloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the file will not help, because presumably you'd just be loading the code from multiple files instead of one file.

In fact, it has been shown that performance gets significantly better if you append files together instead of forcing the PHP request to load a lot of individual PHP code files.

If you are at all concerned with performance, you should be using a [PHP bytecode cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612945).

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with large PHP file. But if you want to divide your code in separate files this will help you in fixing the bug and in code reusability.

It will not affect in response time or performance of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In any case it will have the best response time with the given code since it will need to read that one file only.

The problem with having a single monolithic file is it will make it harder to maintain

Answer (score 0):

try to improve reusabilty and readability of your code. There are no rules about the lenght of your code.