# php deprecated warning is only if file changed

Tags: php, error-reporting

I intentionally set my error_reporting, so I see the E_DEPRECATED warnings while developing.

Now on some ocations those warnings are not shown: I successfully get the warning

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ... has a deprecated constructor

But only if the file time changed. If I reload the page, the warning is gone. If I touch the file again on the filesystem and then reload the page, it is there.

I know how to fix the error, but how
 do I turn this "feature" off?

What do I have to do to get the warning **always**?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a caching issue. Are you using opcache or memcached or something like that?

Comment: How do those caches work? Do they filter error messages? I use php7.4 in this Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/tan3/php-apache

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612945/what-is-a-bytecode-cache-and-how-can-i-use-one-in-php

Comment: That Docker image you're using includes the `apcu` extension

Comment: The warning comes from the PHP compiler. The cache prevents recompiling the script, it saves the compiled version.

Comment: So how do I turn this unwanted cache off during development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't install opcache in your docker image, so edit this line:

```
  docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl mysqli soap gd zip opcache && \
```

to just

```
  docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl mysqli soap gd zip && \
```

and rebuild the image.

This will work for sure, but you probably can also edit the php.ini and disable opcache there